# Nested loop does not run properly

Tags: vba, excel

[image: This is the output of the code. It removed all reference errors except for this cell]I have a nested loop which first changes all ref cells to white font using a for loop and in a sub for loop the ref cells are deleted. The code runs but has still one or two cells with reference errors. Would need help to sort out the code so that it can remove all reference errors instead of most of it! Thank you .

```
Sub Delete_ref_basedontextcondition()
    Dim R As Range
    Dim w As Long, ref As Range
    Dim refi As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    'Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
        Set R = Application.InputBox("Select cells To be deleted", Type:=8)
        Dim rng As Range
        If TypeName(R) <> "Range" Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
            R.Delete
        End If
        For w = 1 To Worksheets.Count
            With Worksheets(w)
                For Each ref In .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
                    If ref.Text = "#REF!" Then
                        ref.Font.ColorIndex = 2
                        For Each refi In .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
                            If refi.Text = "#REF!" Then
                                refi.Delete
                            End If
                        Next refi
                    End If
                Next ref
            End With
        Next w
End Sub
```

Comment: why do you mark the cells with a corrupt reference with white font first and delete it afterwards?

Comment: Why do you need the second `for each loop`? why don't you use `ref.delete`instead of `ref.font.colorindex = 2 ` and skip the second loop

Comment: it still does an incomplete deletion @psychicebola

Comment: could you provide an example of the expected outcome?

Comment: Please refer to the edit above. After deleting a column of cells it still leaves with one cell that contains a ref error. @psychicebola

Comment: Could it be that deleting a cell with a #REF error is causing another cell which has already been checked in the loop to report a #REF error?  The cell may not contain an error - it's just referencing a cell that does contain an error.  Just a couple of ideas. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm believe that the rogue `#REF!` is actually created by `refi.Delete` so it is missed by the loop that was defined prior to its creation. Use `refi.Clear` instead. You just want to remove the bad formula; you do not want to delete the cell and shift other cells around it (thereby creating new `#REF!` errors).

Think of it as a Pez dispenser full of #REF! errors. Every time you pop one out, another comes in to take its place. Close the lid with `.Clear` instead of spiralling through popping them out with `.Delete`.

Comment: I need to delete as the data deleted and referenced are in two different sheets. For example i have a table containing fruits,colours and price in 3 columns respectively. if i were to clear contents for colours there would be a gap in between the fruits and price.

Comment: even if i were to use just one loop to delete reference cells it gives the same problem so it  is not the refi loop.